# Get Add my own content to gmail compose box using inboxsdk

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, browser-extension, inboxsdk

I am developing a chrome addon and I want to append my own content at the end to mail content using [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/). I am using the following code, but it's appending to my cursor position in Gmail Compose Box.

```
var cv = event.composeView;
cv.insertTextIntoBodyAtCursor('My Content');
```

also, I want to append content before sending mail. So, How I can achieve it using InboxSDK.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could just get the whole messages body, modify and set the modified version as the new messages body. There is two ways to approach it.

**1. getBodyElement()**

Get the whole messages HTML and append whatever you want to append and set this as the new body HTML.

```
var $content = $(composeView.getBodyElement());
var $myContent = $('<div class="my_content">Hello World!</div>');

$content.append($myContent );
composeView.setBodyHTML($content.html());
```

**2. getHTMLContent()**

It would also work with the HTML string of the messages body.

```
var contentString = composeView.getHTMLContent();
var myContent = '<div class="my_content">Hello World!</div>';

contentString += myContent;
composeView.setBodyHTML(contentString);
```